# Should the Constraint Layout wrap all other Views?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, android-constraintlayout

Since the new Constraint Layout has been introduced and it's created by default whenever you create a new Activity, by convention do I have wrap other View Groups (Linear Layout, Relative Layout, etc) inside the Constraint Layout at all times now?

Or can I simply remove the Constraint Layout and continue to use the other View Groups as the root layout?

I am asking because I want to clarify if Google will be making it the norm to have all View Groups wrapped inside the Constraint Layout or eventually stop using the older View Groups altogether.

Answer (score 0):

They won't remove the other layouts, each layout have it's pros, the default template just happens to create activities with constraint layout that doesn't mean anything, I just replace it with coordinator layout cause I need to use it on my app.